# Отображение таблицы падения тела

Tags: pascal, физика

Тело падает с высоты H. Составить программу расчета таблицы значений отражающей:
 - изменение скорости падения тела по мере его приближения к земле.

```
program p2;

const
  G = 9.81;

var 
  h, t, u: real;

begin 
  write('Введите высоту с которого падает тело: ');

  readln(h); 
  t := sqrt(2*h/G);

  while t > 0 do
    begin
      t := t - 1;

      u := sqrt(2*G*h);       
      if t <= 0 then
        writeln('Время: ', t, ', скорость: ', u)
      else
        begin     
          writeln('Время: ', t, ', скорость: ', u);
          h := h-sqr(t)*G/2
        end;
    end; 
end.
```

Но, программа работает неправильно. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Поправте код.  
Помните, что перед и после кода должны быть пустые строки

Comment: @samoilow, всё-равно, парсер обрезает код.

Comment: u := G * t;

Comment: <a href='http://imghost.in/'><img src="http://imghost.in/img/2013-12/12/xdhsqn5o6c2ryresa98rhu8l6.png"></a>

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сократил код до такого:

```
const  G = 9.81;        
var  h, t, t1, u: real;

begin 
  write('Введите высоту с которого падает тело: ');  
  readln(h); 
  t := sqrt(2*h/G); 
  t1 := t;
  writeln('Тело упадет за ', t, ' секунд');

  while t > 0 do        
    begin
      u := G * (t1 - t);
      writeln('Время: ', t1 - t, ', скорость: ', u);
      t := t - 1;
    end; 
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Введите высоту в 1 метр и программа зациклится.

Comment: Добавил t := t - 1;

Comment: @iNeeXT, поправил. Сильно не замарачивался, наверняка можно сделать лучше.